# ClassNotFoundException when running sample MySQL code in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, exception

I'm trying to compile and run the sample code shown below, but it gives me a ClassNotFoundException. I was wondering what the best way to resolve this issue in eclipse would be, as I'm new to the software. I've read many answers on the site about this exception and what may cause it, but I cannot understand alot of the solutions, so I would greatly appreciate if someone could give me a simple explanation for what's causing the problem. Thank you.

```
public class Model{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
       Model myDbTest = new Model();
       myDbTest.displayDbProperties();
    }

     private java.sql.Connection  con = null;
     private final String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://";
     private final String serverName= "localhost";
     private final String portNumber = "1433";
     private final String databaseName= "pubs";
     private final String userName = "user";
     private final String password = "password";
     // Informs the driver to use server a side-cursor, 
     // which permits more than one active statement 
     // on a connection.
     private final String selectMethod = "cursor"; 

     // Constructor
     public Model(){}

     private String getConnectionUrl(){
          return url+serverName+":"+portNumber+";databaseName="+databaseName+";selectMethod="+selectMethod+";";
     }

     private java.sql.Connection getConnection(){
          try{
               Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"); 
               con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(),userName,password);
               if(con!=null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
          }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : " + e.getMessage());
         }
          return con;
      }

     /*
          Display the driver properties, database details 
     */ 

     public void displayDbProperties(){
          java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dm = null;
          java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
          try{
               con= this.getConnection();
               if(con!=null){
                    dm = con.getMetaData();
                    System.out.println("Driver Information");
                    System.out.println("\tDriver Name: "+ dm.getDriverName());
                    System.out.println("\tDriver Version: "+ dm.getDriverVersion ());
                    System.out.println("\nDatabase Information ");
                    System.out.println("\tDatabase Name: "+ dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                    System.out.println("\tDatabase Version: "+ dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                    System.out.println("Avalilable Catalogs ");
                    rs = dm.getCatalogs();
                    while(rs.next()){
                         System.out.println("\tcatalog: "+ rs.getString(1));
                    } 
                    rs.close();
                    rs = null;
                    closeConnection();
               }else System.out.println("Error: No active Connection");
          }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          dm=null;
     }     

     private void closeConnection(){
          try{
               if(con!=null)
                    con.close();
               con=null;
          }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

The error is printed as:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriverError Trace in getConnection() : com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
Error: No active Connection

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Model.getConnection(Model.java:30)
    at Model.displayDbProperties(Model.java:48)
    at Model.main(Model.java:6)
```

Comment: can you copy and paste your error for us?

Comment: please give us the stacktrace

Comment: ur main method is put the wrong way , as u put it,I think it will only run ur `displayDbProperties` method,  ur main method should be in a different class or u need to rearrange ur code.

Comment: I've included the error message in my question, also I've added the mySql jar file into the javaBuildPath, so I don't receive any errors about the MySQL classes being unrecognsed

Comment: also, how can I check which jar files are included in my classpath

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JAR of your JDBC driver is not included in the classpath when running your source code. But as others mentioned, stacktrace is probably needed to further help you.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you haven't MsSQLServer jdbc driver in your .classpath

Look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b425c201-9882-4a48-b049-4004f202b0c6/javalangclassnotfoundexception-commicrosoftsqlserverjdbcsqlserverdriver?forum=sqldataaccess)